# How best to represent the addition to / presence of pairs?

Tags: website-design, forms, interaction-design

I'm currently designing a dashboard that allows a user to manage [ANDSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANDSF) policies. The Policy model allows for a number of start time/end time pairs to be added to it.

Currently, policies are created through a simple form. What would be the best way to design a form to allow the intuitive addition of zero or more time pairs? Also, if I am representing already created policies in a section of markup, what is the best way to represent a list of pairs?

Answer (score 1):

For adding - you could use 2 fields, or if you are using a timeline you could give the user the options to mark sections on it (similar to scheduling a meeting in Outlook)

For time pairs display using a timeline or a clock could be a nice experience(see here - http://www.boingboing.net/filesroot/200709241426.jpg).
Of course there is a great chance you couldn't avoid a textual display as well (for sorting, copy paste etc.). If it's not a long list, maybe something like this could work:

[image: sketch]